# Algorithm to draw sprites on infinite map

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a game on HTML5 canvas(It's infinite), and I want to make bushes in my game randomly from Perlin noise. I want chunks to be a 16 by 16 grid of tiles, and every tile is 85 pixels away from each other. I just draw the grid with this simple code:

```
ctx.lineWidth=4,ctx.strokeStyle="#000",ctx.globalAlpha=.06,ctx.beginPath();
for(var p=-5;p<canvas.width;p+=85){ctx.moveTo(p + (offset[0] % 85),0),ctx.lineTo(p + (offset[0] % 85),canvas.height)};
for(var m=-5;m<canvas.height;m+=85){ctx.moveTo(0,m + (offset[1] % 85)),ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,m + (offset[1] % 85))};
ctx.stroke();
ctx.globalAlpha=1;
```

here's the current code I have for bushes, but I don't know how to make it actually work:

```
for(x=offset[0];x<offset[0]+16;x++) {
        for(y=offset[1];y<offset[1]+16;y++) {
            if (noise.perlin2(x / 10, y/10) < -0.6) {
              ctx.drawImage(treeimage,  x, y)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have access to the current chunk of the player, and the offset of objects based on the player's current position (just adding and subtracting to/from it when the player presses an arrow key).

EDIT: 
Sorry, I didn't explain this correctly. The images show, I can't figure out how to make the bushes have the correct position on the screen when the player moves around, and/or make the 8 chunks around the player also load, but only show when stuff is on the screen.

Just an example:

Before I move just a bit:
[image]

After I move just a bit:
[image]

Comment: A fiddle would be very useful.

Comment: I have a few sprites in the game and multiple javascript files. Sorry, it would just be too much work to upload all the image files, etc.

Comment: Where you get the image variable "treeimage"? 
One cannot call the drawImage() method before the image has actually loaded.

Comment: It's just in an images folder.

Comment: as in, `var treeimage = new Image();treeimage.src = 'images/mapobjects/tree2.png';`

Answer (score 0):

Before you call

```
ctx.drawImage(treeimage,  x, y)
```

You must make sure that image is retrieved from server.

One way to do it is insert a little IMG tag on page and later retrieve image from it

```
<img id="treeimage" src="images/mapobjects/tree2.png" style="display:none;">

window.onload = function() { //use onload if you create drawing at page load 
var treeimage = document.getElementById("treeimage");
ctx.drawImage(treeimage, x, y);
}
```

Another way is to create IMG tag by code and never display it but ensure it has onload function. After its called since now you can use your image anytime.

```
window.treeimage = document.createElement('img'); //make it global or take care about scope
treeimage.src = "images/mapobjects/tree2.png";

treeimage.onload = function(){
  //only from now you can use that image
  ctx.drawImage(treeimage, x, y);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my issues correctly. I've updated the question now.

Comment: Could you explain whats currently happening with bushes and chunks when player moves around. Any screenshot would be desirable

Comment: basically the bushes get totally different when you move to a new chunk, and I can't figure out how to load the 9 chunks around the player but only show the bushes on the screen.

Comment: Could you please add 2 screenshots of your application: before player moves and after player moves.

Comment: Unfortunately from provided information I can't point out the problem.
If you still need help you can zip your whole project and send it to my email: arturs_mednis@inbox.lv